# While trying to use the External Sevices I get the error "Error encountered while saving External Registration. Please try again later."

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, json, callout

I am trying to connect a REST API to the "Find An Apprenticeship" web service.

I am trying to do this via Salesforce's "External Service".
I have set up the "Named Credential" [image: Named Credentials]
and now trying to put the "Swagger"/"Open API" in. But I get this error which I can't find anywhere.
[image: External Service]

This is the JSON Code:

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Manage vacancies API (Sandbox)",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Manage vacancies API (Sandbox)"
  },
  "host": "apis.apprenticeships.sfa.bis.gov.uk",
  "basePath": "/manage-vacancies-sandbox",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "securityDefinitions": {
    "apiKeyHeader": {
      "type": "apiKey",
      "name": "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",
      "in": "header"
    },
    "apiKeyQuery": {
      "type": "apiKey",
      "name": "subscription-key",
      "in": "query"
    }
  },
  "security": [
    {
      "apiKeyHeader": []
    },
    {
      "apiKeyQuery": []
    }
  ],
  "x-servers": [
    {
      "url": "https://apis.apprenticeships.sfa.bis.gov.uk"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://apis.apprenticeships.education.gov.uk"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/v1/apprenticeships": {
      "post": {
        "description": "The apprenticeship operation creates an apprenticeship vacancy using the specified values.\r\n\r\n#### Restricted values ####\r\n\r\nThese fields will only accept specific values as listed below:\r\n* ApplicationMethod\r\n    - Online\r\n    - Offline\r\n* LocationType\r\n    - OtherLocation\r\n    - EmployerLocation\r\n    - Nationwide\r\n* DurationType\r\n    - Weeks\r\n    - Months\r\n    - Years\r\n* WageType\r\n    - CustomWageFixed\r\n    - CustomWageRange\r\n    - NationalMinimumWage\r\n    - ApprenticeshipMinimumWage\r\n    - Unwaged\r\n    - CompetitiveSalary\r\n    - ToBeSpecified\r\n* WageUnit\r\n    - NotApplicable\r\n    - Weekly\r\n    - Monthly\r\n    - Annually\r\n* TrainingType\r\n    - Framework\r\n    - Standard\r\n\r\n#### Validation rules ####\r\n\r\nWhen creating a vacancy the following rules must be considered. \r\n1. All values are required to be populated except in the following cases:\r\n\r\n* For all vacancies these values are optional\r\n    - ContactName\r\n    - ContactEmail\r\n    - ContactNumber\r\n    - ThingsToConsider\r\n\r\n* For an Online vacancy\r\n    - SupplementaryQuestion1 and SupplementaryQuestion2 are optional\r\n    - ExternalApplicationUrl and ExternalApplicationInstructions must be empty\r\n\r\n* For an Offline vacancy\r\n    - ExternalApplicationInstructions is optional\r\n    - SupplementaryQuestion1 and SupplementaryQuestion2 must be empty\r\n\r\n* When LocationType is EmployerLocation or Nationwide \r\n    - Location is not required.\r\n\r\n* When LocationType is OtherLocation \r\n    - Only Address1, Town and Postcode are required\r\n    - All other address fields are optional\r\n\r\n* When WageType is CustomWageFixed\r\n    - WageTypeReason must be empty\r\n    - WageUnit must be a value other than NotApplicable\r\n    - MinWage and MaxWage must be empty\r\n    - FixedWage must be greater than or equal to the Apprenticeship minimum wage \r\n\r\n* When WageType is CustomWageRange\r\n    - WageTypeReason must be empty\r\n    - WageUnit must be a value other than NotApplicable\r\n    - MinWage must be greater than or equal to the Apprenticeship minimum wage \r\n    - MaxWage must be greater than MinWage\r\n    - FixedWage must be empty\r\n\r\n* When WageType is NationalMinimumWage or ApprenticeshipMinimumWage\r\n    - MinWage, MaxWage, FixedWage and WageTypeReason must be empty\r\n    - WageUnit must be NotApplicable\r\n\r\n* When WageType is Unwaged, CompetitiveSalary or ToBeSpecified\r\n    - FixedWage, MinWage and MaxWage must be empty\r\n    - WageUnit must be NotApplicable\r\n\r\n* When TrainingType is Framework\r\n    - TrainingCode should be in format ###-##-##\r\n\r\n* When TrainingType is Standard\r\n    - TrainingCode should be a numeric value no greater than 9999\r\n\r\n* Text fields will take a maximum of 4,000 characters except for the following\r\n    - Title = 100\r\n    - ShortDescription = 350\r\n    - ContactName = 100\r\n    - ContactEmail = 100\r\n    - AddressLine = 300\r\n    - Town = 100\r\n    - WageTypeReason = 240\r\n    - WorkingWeek = 250\r\n\r\n* Additional rules\r\n    - Title must include the word ***apprentice***\r\n    - HoursPerWeek must be between 16 and 48 inclusive\r\n    - ExpectedDuration must be a minimum of 1 year, 12 months or 52 weeks depending on the value of DurationType selected\r\n    - NumberOfPositions must not exceed 5,000\r\n\r\n#### Error codes ####\r\n\r\nThe following error codes may be returned when calling this operation if any of the vacancy values \r\nspecified fail validation:\r\n\r\n| Error code  | Explanation                                 |\r\n| ----------- | ------------------------------------------- |\r\n| 31000       | Invalid Request body                        |\r\n| 31001       | Invalid Title                               |\r\n| 31002       | Invalid Short description                   |\r\n| 31003       | Invalid Long description                    |\r\n| 31004       | Invalid Application closing date            |\r\n| 31005       | Invalid Expected start date                 |\r\n| 31006       | Invalid Working week                        |\r\n| 31007       | Invalid Hours per week                      |\r\n| 31008       | Invalid Wage type                           |\r\n| 31009       | Invalid Wage type reason                    |\r\n| 31010       | Invalid Wage unit                           |\r\n| 31011       | Invalid Fixed wage                          |\r\n| 31012       | Invalid Min wage                            |\r\n| 31013       | Invalid Max wage                            |\r\n| 31014       | Invalid Expected duration                   |\r\n| 31015       | Invalid Duration type                       |\r\n| 31016       | Invalid Location type                       |\r\n| 31017       | Invalid Location Address line 1             |\r\n| 31018       | Invalid Location Address line 2             |\r\n| 31019       | Invalid Location Address line 3             |\r\n| 31020       | Invalid Location Address line 4             |\r\n| 31021       | Invalid Location Address line 5             |\r\n| 31022       | Invalid Location Town                       |\r\n| 31023       | Invalid Location Postcode                   |\r\n| 31024       | Invalid Number of positions                 |\r\n| 31025       | Invalid Provider's Ukprn                    |\r\n| 31026       | Invalid Employer's Edsurn                   |\r\n| 31027       | Invalid Provider site's Edsurn              |\r\n| 31028       | Invalid Contact Name                        |\r\n| 31029       | Invalid Contact Email                       |\r\n| 31030       | Invalid Contact Number                      |\r\n| 31031       | Invalid Training Type                       |\r\n| 31032       | Invalid Training Code                       |\r\n| 31033       | Invalid Desired skills                      |\r\n| 31034       | Invalid Desired personal qualities          |\r\n| 31035       | Invalid Desired qualifications              |\r\n| 31036       | Invalid Future prospects                    |\r\n| 31037       | Invalid Things to consider                  |\r\n| 31038       | Invalid Training to be provided             |\r\n| 31039       | Invalid Application method                  |\r\n| 31040       | Invalid Supplementary question 1            |\r\n| 31041       | Invalid Supplementary question 2            |\r\n| 31042       | Invalid External application url            |\r\n| 31043       | Invalid External Application Instructions   |\r\n| 31044       | Invalid Is Employer Disability Confident    |\r\n| 31045       | Invalid Location Additional Information     |\r\n| 31046       | Invalid Employer Description                |\r\n| 31047       | Invalid Employer Website Url                |",
        "operationId": "CreateApprenticeshipVacancy",
        "summary": "CreateApprenticeshipVacancy",
        "tags": [
          "Apprenticeships"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "createApprenticeshipParameters",
            "in": "body",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/CreateApprenticeshipParameters"
            }
          }
        ],
        "consumes": [
          "application/json",
          "text/json",
          "application/xml",
          "text/xml",
          "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "application/json",
          "text/json",
          "application/xml",
          "text/xml"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/CreateApprenticeshipResponse"
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Failed request validation",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/BadRequestContent"
            }
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Invalid provider ukprn",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/StringContent"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "CreateApprenticeshipParameters": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "shortDescription": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "longDescription": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "desiredSkills": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "desiredPersonalQualities": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "desiredQualifications": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "futureProspects": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "thingsToConsider": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "trainingToBeProvided": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "applicationMethod": {
          "enum": [
            "Online",
            "Offline"
          ],
          "type": "string"
        },
        "supplementaryQuestion1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "supplementaryQuestion2": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "externalApplicationUrl": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "externalApplicationInstructions": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "expectedDuration": {
          "format": "int32",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "durationType": {
          "enum": [
            "Weeks",
            "Months",
            "Years"
          ],
          "type": "string"
        },
        "applicationClosingDate": {
          "format": "date-time",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "expectedStartDate": {
          "format": "date-time",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "workingWeek": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "hoursPerWeek": {
          "format": "double",
          "type": "number"
        },
        "wageType": {
          "enum": [
            "CustomWageFixed",
            "CustomWageRange",
            "NationalMinimumWage",
            "ApprenticeshipMinimumWage",
            "Unwaged",
            "CompetitiveSalary",
            "ToBeSpecified"
          ],
          "type": "string"
        },
        "wageTypeReason": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "wageUnit": {
          "enum": [
            "NotApplicable",
            "Weekly",
            "Monthly",
            "Annually"
          ],
          "type": "string"
        },
        "minWage": {
          "format": "double",
          "type": "number"
        },
        "maxWage": {
          "format": "double",
          "type": "number"
        },
        "fixedWage": {
          "format": "double",
          "type": "number"
        },
        "locationType": {
          "enum": [
            "OtherLocation",
            "EmployerLocation",
            "Nationwide"
          ],
          "type": "string"
        },
        "location": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Location"
        },
        "numberOfPositions": {
          "format": "int32",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "employerEdsUrn": {
          "format": "int32",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "providerSiteEdsUrn": {
          "format": "int32",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "contactName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "contactEmail": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "contactNumber": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "trainingType": {
          "enum": [
            "Framework",
            "Standard"
          ],
          "type": "string"
        },
        "trainingCode": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "isEmployerDisabilityConfident": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "employerWebsiteUrl": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "employerDescription": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "Location": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "addressLine1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "addressLine2": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "addressLine3": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "addressLine4": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "addressLine5": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "postcode": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "town": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "additionalInformation": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "CreateApprenticeshipResponse": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "vacancyReferenceNumber": {
          "format": "int32",
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    },
    "BadRequestContent": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "requestErrors": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/BadRequestError"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "BadRequestError": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "errorCode": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "errorMessage": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "StringContent": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "headers": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/KeyValuePair[String,IEnumerable[String]]"
          },
          "readOnly": true
        }
      }
    },
    "KeyValuePair[String,IEnumerable[String]]": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "type": "string",
          "readOnly": true
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "readOnly": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "tags": []
}
```

Any help on what this error could relate to would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.
(I'm also in a sandbox if that makes a difference)

Comment: are you able to even save a simple schema? normally you would get an Invalid Schema error at that point, not seen that before

Comment: actually, just tried to save your schema and i get the same error - try deleting chunks until by a process of elimination you find the issue

Comment: Okay I'll give that a go thankyou Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I answered [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9062I000000Qyi2), it appears to be an issue with the description. Fixing the description part should help solve the error and take you to the next step.

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Manage vacancies API (Sandbox)",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Manage vacancies API (Sandbox)"
  },
  "host": "apis.apprenticeships.sfa.bis.gov.uk",
  "basePath": "/manage-vacancies-sandbox",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "securityDefinitions": {
    "apiKeyHeader": {
      "type": "apiKey",
      "name": "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",
      "in": "header"
    },
    "apiKeyQuery": {
      "type": "apiKey",
      "name": "subscription-key",
      "in": "query"
    }
  },
  "security": [
    {
      "apiKeyHeader": []
    },
    {
      "apiKeyQuery": []
    }
  ],
  "x-servers": [
    {
      "url": "https://apis.apprenticeships.sfa.bis.gov.uk"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://apis.apprenticeships.education.gov.uk"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/v1/apprenticeships": {
      "post": {
        "description": "",
        "operationId": "CreateApprenticeshipVacancy",
        "summary": "CreateApprenticeshipVacancy",
        "tags": [
          "Apprenticeships"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "createApprenticeshipParameters",
            "in": "body",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/CreateApprenticeshipParameters"
            }
          }
        ],
        "consumes": [
          "application/json",
          "text/json",
          "application/xml",
          "text/xml",
          "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "application/json",
          "text/json",
          "application/xml",
          "text/xml"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/CreateApprenticeshipResponse"
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Failed request validation",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/BadRequestContent"
            }
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Invalid provider ukprn",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/StringContent"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "CreateApprenticeshipParameters": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "shortDescription": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "longDescription": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "desiredSkills": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "desiredPersonalQualities": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "desiredQualifications": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "futureProspects": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "thingsToConsider": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "trainingToBeProvided": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "applicationMethod": {
          "enum": [
            "Online",
            "Offline"
          ],
          "type": "string"
        },
        "supplementaryQuestion1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "supplementaryQuestion2": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "externalApplicationUrl": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "externalApplicationInstructions": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "expectedDuration": {
          "format": "int32",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "durationType": {
          "enum": [
            "Weeks",
            "Months",
            "Years"
          ],
          "type": "string"
        },
        "applicationClosingDate": {
          "format": "date-time",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "expectedStartDate": {
          "format": "date-time",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "workingWeek": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "hoursPerWeek": {
          "format": "double",
          "type": "number"
        },
        "wageType": {
          "enum": [
            "CustomWageFixed",
            "CustomWageRange",
            "NationalMinimumWage",
            "ApprenticeshipMinimumWage",
            "Unwaged",
            "CompetitiveSalary",
            "ToBeSpecified"
          ],
          "type": "string"
        },
        "wageTypeReason": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "wageUnit": {
          "enum": [
            "NotApplicable",
            "Weekly",
            "Monthly",
            "Annually"
          ],
          "type": "string"
        },
        "minWage": {
          "format": "double",
          "type": "number"
        },
        "maxWage": {
          "format": "double",
          "type": "number"
        },
        "fixedWage": {
          "format": "double",
          "type": "number"
        },
        "locationType": {
          "enum": [
            "OtherLocation",
            "EmployerLocation",
            "Nationwide"
          ],
          "type": "string"
        },
        "location": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Location"
        },
        "numberOfPositions": {
          "format": "int32",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "employerEdsUrn": {
          "format": "int32",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "providerSiteEdsUrn": {
          "format": "int32",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "contactName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "contactEmail": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "contactNumber": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "trainingType": {
          "enum": [
            "Framework",
            "Standard"
          ],
          "type": "string"
        },
        "trainingCode": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "isEmployerDisabilityConfident": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "employerWebsiteUrl": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "employerDescription": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "Location": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "addressLine1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "addressLine2": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "addressLine3": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "addressLine4": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "addressLine5": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "postcode": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "town": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "additionalInformation": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "CreateApprenticeshipResponse": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "vacancyReferenceNumber": {
          "format": "int32",
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    },
    "BadRequestContent": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "requestErrors": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/BadRequestError"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "BadRequestError": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "errorCode": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "errorMessage": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "StringContent": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "headers": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/KeyValuePair[String,IEnumerable[String]]"
          },
          "readOnly": true
        }
      }
    },
    "KeyValuePair[String,IEnumerable[String]]": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "type": "string",
          "readOnly": true
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "readOnly": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "tags": []
}
```